# delete image from path and database

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following errors:

> Warning: unlink() [function.unlink]: Invalid argument in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\SH\owner\delete_img.php 
>       on line 11

and

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
>       to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       '* FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='"73"'' at line 1

This is my code for delete image. My images have own imgid. I want to delete it using their imgid.

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","")or die("could not connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("sh",$link) or die ("could not select database");

    $imgid = $_GET['imgid'];
    // sending query
    $select=mysql_query("SELECT location FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'");
    $img=mysql_fetch_array($select);
    unlink($img['location']);
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE * FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'")
    or die(mysql_error());      

    header("Location: editimage1.php");
?>
```

This is the link of one of the pictures I want to delete:

```
/SH/owner../data/img1.jpg
```

Comment: check folder permission

Comment: I think your image location path is wrongly sent...

Comment: Your query should be `DELETE FROM`. Remove the `*` from your query. Also, your code is susceptible to SQL injection. You are passing in raw user input into your SQL query. At the very least, you should be escaping out quotations, but it is highly recommended that you also use the MYSQLI or PDO set of functions for database connections and queries.

Comment: @Arun so i have to change it to??

Comment: @mira Yes may be.. but not sure. you have to check

Comment: @9997 still same. No alterations

Comment: @mira Do this. Remove your query from the variable. As in, remove the `$result =` part from your deletion query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment. It's been edited.

Your query should be `DELETE FROM`. Remove the `*` from your query.

The full query: `DELETE FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'`

Also, you can either remove the `$result =` part from your query, or do this.

```
if($result) {
    //Successfully deleted image.
}
```

Also, your code is **highly susceptible to SQL injection**. You are passing in raw user input into your SQL query. At the very least, you should be escaping out quotations, but it is highly recommended that you also use the MYSQLI or PDO set of functions for database connections and queries.

You may also need to need check your permissions for the folder that you are trying to remove the file from. Ideally, folders which house images should be set to `chmod 755`.

http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

This link is a very basic introduction to prepared statements, and also provides links for further reading.

EDIT: Full snippet.

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","")or die("could not connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("sh",$link) or die ("could not select database");
$imgid = $_GET['imgid'];
$imgid = mysql_real_escape_string($imgid);

$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/owner../data/';
// sending query
$select=mysql_query("SELECT location FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'");
$img=mysql_fetch_array($select);
unlink($path.$img['location']);
$result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'") or die(mysql_error()); 

//Check to see if the query can run
if($result) {
    header("Location: editimage1.php");
} else {
    //Query failed. Display an error message here.
}
```

?>

Comment: i have changed it. and no error displayed. but image still no deleted from database and folder. and it still displayed.

Comment: Are you passing in the img parameter? Add `var_dump($imgid);` to your code and see what value it contains. Does that value exist in your database? Also, please don't disregard my comments about using prepared statements. Or at the very least, add this to your code. `$imgid = mysql_real_escape_string($imgid);` This is still not 100% safe, but it is much better than passing in raw inputs.

Comment: can u explain more about remove the $result = part? what kind of code i should use to change it?

Comment: @mira Since you're putting your query into a variable, it doesn't execute. You can either totally remove the variable and just run the query the way it is, or you can keep the `$result` variable and just add that if condition. If the variable is true, then your query ran. If it is false, then your query failed. You should put your final header location tag within the if statement. I'll edit my answer with the full code.

Comment: nothing change it. image still cannot deleted. and display again

Comment: @mira You didn't post the value of `var_dump($imgid);` Add that to your code and see what it says.

Comment: @mira It looks like you've already accepted the answer, but the issue was that your `$imgid` variable was empty. You need to pass in a valid image ID for your query to work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table
$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","")or die("could not connect");
$db=mysql_select_db("sh",$link) or die ("could not select database");

    $imgid = $_GET['imgid'];
    $path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/owner../data/';
    // sending query
    $select=mysql_query("SELECT location FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'");
    $img=mysql_fetch_array($select);
    unlink($path.$img['location']);
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM img_homestay WHERE imgid='$imgid'") or die(mysql_error());     

    header("Location: editimage1.php");
?>
```

Comment: no error displayed. but image still cannot deleted from database and folder.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error basically needs debugging.
First check whether problem is related to unlink() function or in Sql connectivety.
Create another php file n check whether its working for static path

```
<?php
$path='/SH/owner../data/img1.jpg'; // update it as per your filepath..path should be from root
if(unlink($path)) 
{
echo "Deleted file ";
}
else
{
 echo "Not Able to Delete File";
}
?>
```

Lets see what it retruns.

As Part Written by 9997 regarding database connection and query execution seems perfectly fine.

Comment: here is.. Warning: unlink(/SH/owner../data/img1.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\SH\owner\delete_img.php on line 26
Not Able to Delete File

Comment: have you written actual file path insted of "/SH/owner../data/img1.jpg" in line 2